# Why won't my AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer appear?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm trying to make a Swift OsX app that opens the camera and displays what's being recorded.

Right now it's literally just one `ViewController`, the green light turns on which makes me think the recording is starting, but the screen stays grey and nothing appears.

Here's the code for the `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: NSImageView!

    func setUpSession() {
        self.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow

        // Add the default input camera
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
            self.session.addInput(input)
            print("Input added.")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }

        var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        previewLayer.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

        self.view.layer = previewLayer
        self.session.startRunning()
        print("Session running.")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setUpSession()
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

Comment: Doesn't work either. Still just a blank gray screen. In fact, the green camera light turns off as soon as it turns on when I use this line instead of self.view.layer = previewLayer

Comment: You use it for os x I don't you? And why do you need a UIImageView here?

Comment: Yes this is for an OS X application. I just added the UIImageView and rendered it to make sure the ViewController was working and it is.